# Print list of lists into matrix format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have printed the elements of a list of lists like this:

```
['1', 'A']
['1', 'B']
['2', 'A']
['2', 'B']
['3', 'A']
['3', 'B']
```

I am wondering how can I print that elements like this (a **3*2** matrix in this case):

```
['1', 'A']  ['1', 'B']
['2', 'A']  ['2', 'B']
['3', 'A']  ['3', 'B']
```

The **number of rows** is the number of different numbers and the **number of columns** is the number of different letters.

For instance, if I have:

```
['1', 'A']
['1', 'B']
```

The output would be displayed in 1 row and 2 columns:

```
['1', 'A']  ['1', 'B']
```

At this moment I have tried converting the list of lists into a numpy array and try to print the desired output but it does not work:

```
lst = [['1', 'A'],['1', 'B'],['2', 'A'],['2', 'B'],['3', 'A'],['3', 'B']]
arr = numpy.array(lst)
arr = arr.reshape(3,2)
print(*arr)
```

**Examples:**

Input:

```
[['1', 'A'],['1', 'B'] ,['1', 'C'], ['1', 'D']]
```

Output:

```
['1', 'A']['1', 'B'] ['1', 'C'] ['1', 'D']
```

Input:

```
[['1', 'A'],['1', 'B'] ,['1', 'C'], ['1', 'D'],['2', 'A'],['2', 'B'] ,['2', 'C'], ['1', 'D']]
```

Output:

```
['1', 'A']['1', 'B'] ['1', 'C'] ['1', 'D']
['2', 'A']['2', 'B'] ['2', 'C'] ['2', 'D']
```

Input:

```
[['1', 'A'],['1', 'B'],['2', 'A'],['2', 'B'],['3', 'A'],['3', 'B']]
```

Output:

```
['1', 'A']['1', 'B']  
['2', 'A']['2', 'B']
['3', 'A']['3', 'B']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

lst = [['1', 'A'],['1', 'B'],['2', 'A'],['2', 'B'],['3', 'A'],['3', 'B']]

def show(lst):
    df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['number', 'letter'])
    a = []
    for x in df['letter'].unique():
        a.append(np.array(df[df['letter']==x]))
    a = np.array(a)
    for i in range(a.shape[1]):
        p = ' '.join([str(list(a[j,i])) for j in range(a.shape[0])])
        print(p)

show(lst)
```

Output:

```
['1', 'A']['1', 'B']
['2', 'A']['2', 'B']
['3', 'A']['3', 'B']
```

If you have more letters and more rows, then this function will still work.

```
lst = [['1', 'A'],['1', 'B'],['1', 'C'],['1', 'D'],['1', 'E'],['2', 'A'],['2', 'B'],['2', 'C'],['2', 'D'],['2','E'],['3', 'A'],['3', 'B'],['3', 'C'],['3', 'D'], ['3', 'E'],['4', 'A'],['4', 'B'],['4', 'C'],['4', 'D'], ['4', 'E']]

show(lst)
```

Output:

```
['1', 'A'] ['1', 'B'] ['1', 'C'] ['1', 'D'] ['1', 'E']
['2', 'A'] ['2', 'B'] ['2', 'C'] ['2', 'D'] ['2', 'E']
['3', 'A'] ['3', 'B'] ['3', 'C'] ['3', 'D'] ['3', 'E']
['4', 'A'] ['4', 'B'] ['4', 'C'] ['4', 'D'] ['4', 'E']
```

Comment: If I have 1 letter or more than 2 letters, how would it be? Because the output right now only displays A and B in all cases

Comment: @rayqz I have updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: For instance a list with sublists: ['1', 'A'] ['1', 'B'] ['1', 'C'] and ['1', 'D'] -> it only returns ['1', 'A']['1', 'B'] instead of ['1', 'A']['1', 'B'] ['1', 'C'] ['1', 'D'] in a row

Comment: So if there are 3 letters, there should be 3 columns, not always 2 columns. Is it clear now?

Comment: @rayqz could you give an example? like how you want the output to be for the following input?

Comment: I have edited the question and put more examples, check them out pls

Comment: @rayqz I have updated my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a python only version

```
tmp = list(map(str, lst))
s = '\n'.join([' ' .join((l1, l2)) for l1, l2 in zip(tmp[::2], tmp[1::2])])
print(s)

output:
['1', 'A'] ['1', 'B']
['2', 'A'] ['2', 'B']
['3', 'A'] ['3', 'B']
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific list, you probably want to reshape it to `(3, 2, 2)` - i.e. `n_rows * n_cols * n_elements_in_sublist`

```
lst = [['1', 'A'],['1', 'B'],['2', 'A'],['2', 'B'],['3', 'A'],['3', 'B']]
arr = numpy.array(lst).reshape(3, 2, 2)
```

You can extract the `n_rows` and `n_cols` from list as

```
n_rows = len(set(x for x,y in lst))
n_cols = len(set(y for x,y in lst))
```